# Не подключается Slick

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, slider, slick.js

Делал слайдер по тутору с ютуб, но он почему-то не работает.

Вот ссылка на видео:[Видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eK96OuHEEl4&list=RDCMUCE_w6FxGfRKH2fU76raVeog&start_radio=1&t=5416s)
1:47:14

Тут я подключил slick.css:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slick.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Тут создал обертку:

```html
<div class="bike-slider">
  <img class="bike-slider__item" src="images/bike-1.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="bike-slider__item" src="images/bike-2.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="bike-slider__item" src="images/bike-3.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="bike-slider__item" src="images/bike-4.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Подключаю jquery и slick.min.js:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/slick.min.js"></script>
<script type="js/main.js"></script>
```

Js код:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.bike-slider').slick();
});
```

По идее должно получиться так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но у меня выходит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Неправильно прописан код `<script type="js/main.js` замените на `<script src="js/main.js`